# For every integer $n$, does $\{2n+p \mid| p \text{ prime }\}$ contain infinitely many primes?

Tags: prime-numbers

True or false:  For every integer $n$, $\{2n + p \mid p \text{ prime} \}$ contains infinitely many primes?

A conjecture, a theorem or just false?

Comment: "T *of* F" or "T **or** F" ? It's just that twice you wrote "of". And what do you mean by a number containing primes? And what does "prime(i)" mean? Pretty oddly (to say the least) worded question...

Comment: Wow. Three answers to an incomprehensible question.

Comment: Indeed so, @DavidMitra...mistery.:)

Comment: I believe the OP is asking whether the sequence $2n + p$ for fixed integer $n \gt 0$ and prime $p \gt 0$ contains infinitely many primes.  For $n=1$ it amounts to twin prime conjecture, and the truth of the statement is not yet proven.

Comment: Although [posted in Answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/27681/3111) to a somewhat different Question, @JonasMeyer makes much the same points as I do below regarding openness of and partial progress on this problem.

Answer (score 2):

A sensible interpretation asks if:

- Every positive even number $2n$ is the difference of two primes infinitely often.

This is a weaker claim than [Polignac's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polignac%27s_conjecture):

- Every positive even number $2n$ is the difference of two consecutive primes infinitely often.

because the latter asks about an infinite number of [prime gaps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap) of every size $2n$ (credit to @CODE for pointing out the article).  That is, here we ask merely that $2n$ appears as the difference of two (positive) primes infinitely often, not necessarily as the difference of *consecutive* prime numbers.  For the special case $n=1$ ([twin prime conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_prime_conjecture)) there is no distinction to be drawn, since for odd prime $p$ there cannot be a prime between $p$ and $p+2$.

Certainly the conjecture, even in this weakened form or even specialized to $n=1$, is unsettled. However there has been tremendous progress recently, such that *for some* $n \gt 0$ it is known that there are infinitely many prime pairs $p$ and $p+2n$.  First Zhang Yitang [announced a proof](http://phys.org/news/2014-01-mathematical-puzzle-unraveled.html) that for some $2n \lt 70,000,000$, there are infinitely many *prime gaps* of size $2n$.  The upper bound on gap size has been reduced by James Maynard and others, so that [currently we know](http://michaelnielsen.org/polymath1/index.php?title=Bounded_gaps_between_primes) that there are infinitely many prime gaps of size $2n$ for some $2n \le 270$.  [Terence Tao's blog](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2014/02/09/polymath8b-viii-time-to-start-writing-up-the-results/) is a particularly good place to find the latest breaking news in this area.

Abandoning the restriction to consecutive primes should make proving a result *for all* even numbers easier, but to date little progress has been made beyond:

[Chen's Theorem II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chen%27s_theorem) (1973) Every positive even number $2n$ is $m - p$ for infinitely many primes $p$ where $m = p+2n$ has at most two prime factors.

Comment: Thanks to hardmath for polishing my crudely stated question and for the interesting references.  As an amateur I shall be more circumspect and conformist in notation in any future questions ;-)